# How to pin the top header row showing column names in this bootstrap-vue table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a bootstrap-vue table that looks like this;

[image]

Here is the code;

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table hover :items="items"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          {
            age: 89,
            first_name: 'Geneva',
            last_name: 'Wilson',
            _rowVariant: 'danger'
          },
          {
            age: 40,
            first_name: 'Thor',
            last_name: 'MacDonald',
            _cellVariants: { age: 'info', first_name: 'warning' }
          },
          { age: 29, first_name: 'Dick', last_name: 'Dunlap' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Suppose the table has many rows. I would like to pin the top header row such that when I scroll down the table, the header row showing the column names remains at the top. This makes the table more readable.

The table code was provided in bootstrap-vue documentation.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table

I am using Vue v2.6 and BootstrapVue.

Comment: CSS `position: sticky`?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#sticky-headers)?

Comment: @tao, oh ... the keyword is sticky header, right?

Comment: Not exactly a keyword. It's the value of [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: I don't fully understand why you bountied the question after you had the relevant link to docs. Is that link not sufficient to answer your question? Do you need more help?

Comment: @tao, Thanks for your kind offer. I have enough help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BootstrapVue's table provides `sticky-header` prop for this purpose.

As outlined in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#sticky-headers), using

```html
<b-table :sticky-header="true">
  ...table contents here
</b-table>
```

- sets the `height` of the table to `300px`
- sets table's `overflow` to `auto`
- sets table's `position` to `relative`
- sets `position` to `sticky` (`z-index` to `2` and `position` to `relative`) for each `<th />` in the table header

**Important**: the above are required for the table header to be sticky relative to the table, not to the entire page. If you use @LajosArpad's solution, the table will be sticky in relation to the page, and when scrolling past the table the table header will remain visible, which is probably not the desired result.

If you want the table to have any other `height` than `300px`, you have to pass it as the value of `sticky-header` prop:

```html
<b-table sticky-header="80vh">
  ...table contents here
</b-table>
```

---

See it working on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/modest-hill-xyv9v5?file=%2FApp.vue).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I was struggling with how to adjust the height and your answer arrived.  Verified to work!

Comment: The part that made me struggle with setting the table height was this. I tried `<b-table :sticky-header="80vh">`. Didn't work. When I tried your answer, `<b-table sticky-header="80vh">`, it worked. Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: @user3848207, `:sticky-header` is shorthand for `v-bind:sticky-header`. Which interprets the value as a JavaScript expression, whereas `sticky-header="80vh"` interprets the value as string. In other words, `:sticky-header="'80vh'"` is the same as `sticky-header="80vh"` and the same as `v-bind:sticky-header="\"80vh\""`. Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. You have deep understanding of javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to style the element in question with

```
position: sticky;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Where you also have a demo:

```css
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">foo</div>
<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>
```

You will therefore need to look into what the structure is that Vue generates for you and make sure you make the style of `position: sticky;` to the element whose `position` needs to be `sticky`.